# Create a new .txt file for each .pdf files in a directory in python

Tags: python, loops, file-io, directory, file-handling

My code is supposed to take each pdf from a directory, OCR it and return a .txt file for each OCR'd pdf. The name of the pdf and the .txt file should be the same except .pdf being changed to .txt. I am stuck in the part of splitting the input pdf name to generate the same name with a .txt extension for a OCR'd file. A sample file in the directory looks like this : "000dbf9d-d53f-465f-a7ce-722722136fb7465.pdf". I need output as "000dbf9d-d53f-465f-a7ce-722722136fb7465.txt". Also my code doesn't create new .txt files but overwrites on one file for each iteration. I need a new .txt file for each OCR'd .pdf files. Code till now:

```
import io
import glob
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi


files = glob.glob(r"D:\files\**")
for file in files:
    #print(file)
    pdf = wi(filename = file, resolution = 300)

    pdfImg = pdf.convert('jpeg')

    imgBlobs = []

    for img in pdfImg.sequence:
        page = wi(image = img)
        imgBlobs.append(page.make_blob('jpeg'))

    extracted_texts = []

    for imgBlob in imgBlobs:
            im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')
            extracted_texts.append(text)          
    with open("D:\\extracted_text\\"+ "\\file1.txt", 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(extracted_texts))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to keep track of your file name and re-use it in the last two lines:

```
# ...
import os


files = glob.glob(r"D:\files\**")
for file in files:
    #print(file)

    # Get the name of the file less any suffixes
    name = os.path.basename(file).split('.')[0]

    # ...

    # Use `name` from above to name your text file         
    with open("D:\\extracted_text\\" + name + ".txt", 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(extracted_texts))
```